# Finding the characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

> let $A$ be \begin{pmatrix}
>     7 & -5 & -4  \\
>     -1 & -2 & 1\\
>     9 & -5 & -6
> \end{pmatrix}
>
> find the characteristic polynomial, eigenvalues and eigenvectors

So we need to find $|x\cdot I-A|=0$ or in this case:

\begin{vmatrix}
    x-7 & 5 & 4  \\
    1 & x+2 & -1\\
    -9 & 5 & x+6
\end{vmatrix}

Developing by the first row we get:

$(x-7)\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
      x+2 & -1\\
    5 & x+6
\end{vmatrix}-5\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & -1\\
    -9 & x+6
\end{vmatrix}+4\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & x+2 \\
    -9 & 5 & 
\end{vmatrix}$

$(x-7)[(x+2)(x+6)+5]-5(x+6-9)+4(5-9x-18)=-156-80x+x^2+x^3$

How should I approach from here? can apply I row/columns operations on $|x\cdot I-A|$?

Comment: Pay attention on the signs in $xI-A$. That's why I prefer to compute $A-xI$.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain fixed, thanks

Comment: It seems that you have wrong signs in developing the row.

Comment: Pay attention to the signs of the minors corresponding to $a_{12}$ and $a_{13}$. Anyway, it would be interesting to see how much you can say about eigenvalues even if you are not able to solve the third-degree equation.

Comment: Sorry all, fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some errors in your calculation. The correct solution is:

$$(x-7)\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
      x+2 & -1\\
    5 & x+6
\end{vmatrix}-5\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & -1\\
    -9 & x+6
\end{vmatrix}+4\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & x+2 \\
    -9 & 5 & 
\end{vmatrix}=
$$
$$
=(x-7)[(x+2)(x+6)+5]-5[x+6-9]+4[5+9(x+2)]=
$$
$$
=(x-7)(x^2+8x+17)-5(x-3)+4(9x+23)=x^3+x^2-8x-12
$$
that has an obvious root $x=3$ so can be factorized as $(x-3)(x+2)^2$.

Comment: Since the row sums are all $-2$, $-2$ is also an eigenvalue, with eigenvector $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: Yes! I 've added the factorization.

Comment: @EmilioNovati when you say that "obvious root $x=3$" you just try to find a root by guessing and than use polynomial division?

Comment: Yes. I test the divisors of $12$ and that $x=3$ works. Than dividing by $x-3$ we find the other factor.

Answer (score 1):

You can do elementary operations on lines and columns of determinants, and here, adding 3rd column to the 1st one, then substracting the 1st row to the 3rd will greatly simplify the computations:
\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
    x-7 & 5 & 4  \\
    1 & x+2 & -1\\
    -9 & 5 & x+6
\end{vmatrix}&=
\begin{vmatrix}
    x-3 & 5 & 4  \\
    0 & x+2 & -1\\
    x-3 & 5 & x+6
\end{vmatrix}=
(x-3)\begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 5 & 4  \\
    0 & x+2 & -1\\
    1 & 5 & x+6
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=
(x-3)\begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 5 & 4  \\
    0 & x+2 & -1\\
    0 & 0 & x+2
\end{vmatrix}=(x-3)(x+2)^2.
\end{align*}
You should find $E_3=\langle(1,0,-1)\rangle$ and $E_{-2}=\langle(1,1,1)\rangle$. As $\dim E_{-2}<2$, $A$ is not diagonalisable.